# Can't click on links with Iscroll 5

Tags: scroll, iscroll

i'm using Iscroll 5, i can scroll with this code, i have no problem.
The only problem is with my iphone i can't click on the link, and i don't know why...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scroll;
function loaded() {
    scroll = new IScroll('#contenu', {
    tap:true,
    desktopCompatibility: true,
        scrollbars: true,
        interactiveScrollbars: true,
        freeScroll: true,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollY: true,
        momentum: false,
        onBeforeScrollStart: null,
        mouseWheel: true
    });
}

//disables browser mouse scrolling
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
}

function wheel(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
</script>
```

If i use this code i can click but i can't scroll ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myScroll;
var showkey =true;
function loaded () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#contenu', { 
    tap:true,
    desktopCompatibility: true,
    onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
                var nodeType = e.explicitOriginalTarget ? e.explicitOriginalTarget.nodeName.toLowerCase():(e.target ? e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase():'');

                if(nodeType !='select' && nodeType !='option' && nodeType !='input' && nodeType!='textarea' && !showkey) {
                     e.preventDefault();    //prevents showing keyboard - scrolling
                }//otherwise, show keyboard, do default
                if(!showkey) showkey = true;
            },       
    });
    $('a, input, #sendmsg, .ml_tabs').on('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(iScrollLoad, 200); }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 19):

Set the *click* option of the Iscroll on **true**

[IScroll click documentation](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll#optionsclick)

```
myScroll = new IScroll('#youDIV',
                {
                    scrollX: false, 
                    scrollY: true
                    ,click:true // open click event
                    ,scrollbars: false 
                    ,useTransform: true
                    ,useTransition: false
                    ,probeType:3
                });
```

Comment: `{... click:true, ...}` did the trick. Went crazy last 4 hours. Thanks. +1

Comment: Ran into this tonight, this answer fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

1: You could provide a jsfiddle, in order to check what's wrong with your code.

2: Why disabling mouse scrolling by adding eventlisteners? Just set `mouseWheel: false` and you're fine

3: iScroll captures touchmove events and handles them in order to decide, what the user want's to do. Therefore add this when initializing iScroll:

`document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);`

4: I don't see, why u're setting a custo eventhandler like `onBeforeScrollStart: null` This makes no sense at all.
You can e.g. enable disable iScroll when you dont wanna scroll if some dialogue is open (like a ) like this:

`myScroll.on('beforeScrollStart', function(event)
        {
            if (isDialogOpen){
                myScroll.disable();
            }
            else{
                myScroll.enable();
            }
        });`

5: a simple click eventhandler on e.g. a `<div>` should work as expected

`$( document ).on( "tap", "#mydiv", function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("mydiv clicked!");
    });`

6: When initializnig iScroll use `preventDefault: false, //do not prevent a possible click - we'll take care of it`

Answer (score 1):

"maksim.lin" has GOT IT RIGHT!!  I'm not allowed to vote:
But "click:true" is best, because adding "preventDefault: false" will do the job, but it will cause your mouse(if using PC) to select elements outside the scroll (text selecting and side scrolling gets jerky). "Click:true" fixes the issue on mobile phones, and won't create selection issues on PC.